# inspect http requests in ios simulator/devices

Tags: ios, http, request, web-inspector

I am working on an ios app which communicate with the server via http request. And I want to monitor the network traffic when testing my app in ios simulator/devices.

Is there any software or tools I can used to inspect the http requests of a specified application on mac/ios, just like firebugs for web developers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are several tools in App Store that provide the network traffic monitor feature. But, they could only view iPhone as a whole and stay at that level. In other words, they could only tell how much traffic has been consumed of this iPhone. For each app? No data.

Comment: He's asking how he can see the raw bytes of the http request and response, not traffic totals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Catcher](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/http-catcher/id1445874902) to capture web traffic. It's a Web debugging proxy for iOS, so you can view requests and responses directly on iPhone.

Comment: This seems like a great option. The free version allows capturing of HTTP traffic, while the paid version also allows HTTPS.

Comment: The free version only allows you to capture HTTP traffic, but most apps today use HTTPS as standard, so this is not a viable free solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io) to record/capture all the requests & responses from your app while developing.It will support ios simulators also. Without doing any code change we use this.

First Download the Proxyman app form the above link after that just go through [this](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/ios-simulator) documentation for references.

Answer (score 0):

[Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/ios/) has recently released an iOS version for http traffic monitoring. it is a paid app though. Good news is that you can set up Charles free desktop version then [setup HTTP proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/) from your iOS device.